# Ruby and ActiveRecord initialize

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm studying ActiveRecord integration with Ruby and trying to do the same thing I've done without it, but keep on failing.

Here's what I've done without AR:

```
 class User

  include FirstLastAge

  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name, :age

  @@all = []

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def initialize(first_name = first.sample, last_name = last.sample, age = rand_age)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @age = age
    self.class.all << self
  end

end

# dat = SQLite3::Database.new('test.db')
# dat.execute("CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT, age INTEGER);")
```

FirstLastAge is a module with 3 methods, #first returns an array of first names, #last and #rand_age.

With this setup I'm able to 5000.times User.new and then iterate through them and create an entry in the DB.

So now I was trying to do the same with AR but with no luck at all.

```
# User class
require_relative '../modules/names.rb'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FirstLastAge
end
```

With this schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "age"
  end

end
```

Got this results:

```
4] pry(main)> a = User.new
=> #<User:0x00007fb8bc1e16b8 id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, age: nil>
[5] pry(main)> a.first #Calling from the module
=> "Rossi"
[6] pry(main)> a.first #Calling from the module
=> "Xander"
[7] pry(main)> a.last #Calling from the module
=> "Patton"
[8] pry(main)> a.rand_age #Calling from the module
=> 11
[9] pry(main)> x = User.new(first_name: 'Alex', last_name: "Patton", age: 45)
=> #<User:0x00007fb8bdf1ccc8 id: nil, first_name: "Alex", last_name: "Patton", age: 45>
[10] pry(main)> y = User.new(first_name: first, last_name: "Patton", age: 45)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `first' for main:Object
from (pry):7:in `__pry__'
[11] pry(main)> y = User.new(first_name: self.first, last_name: "Patton", age: 45)
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for main:Object
from (pry):8:in `__pry__'
[12] pry(main)> y = User.new(first_name: User.first, last_name: "Patton", age: 45)
=> #<User:0x00007fb8bc4a9bc0 id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: "Patton", age: 45>
[13] pry(main)> y = User.new(first_name: User.first, last_name: "Patton", age: User.rand_age)
NoMethodError: undefined method `rand_age' for #<Class:0x00007fb8bc4a36d0>
from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

Last thing I've tried, that works, but I cannot understand why and also don't even know if it's the right way is:

```
34] pry(main)> 
[35] pry(main)> 
[36] pry(main)> User.new.first
=> "Rihan"
[37] pry(main)> User.new.last
=> "Beck"
[38] pry(main)> User.new.rand_age
=> 24
[39] pry(main)> x = User.new(first_name: User.new.first, last_name: User.new.last, age: User.new.rand)
User.new.rand           User.new.random_add     User.new.random_iv      User.new.random_number  
User.new.rand_age       User.new.random_bytes   User.new.random_key     
[39] pry(main)> x = User.new(first_name: User.new.first, last_name: User.new.last, age: User.new.rand_age)
=> #<User:0x00007fc664559588 id: nil, first_name: "Taylan", last_name: "Trevino", age: 74>
[40] pry(main)> y = User.new(first_name: User.new.first, last_name: User.new.last, age: User.new.rand_age)
=> #<User:0x00007fc6630dfd50 id: nil, first_name: "Sanaullah", last_name: "Koch", age: 56>
[41] pry(main)>
```

Any idea on what is happening, and how would you do this?

Thank you.

Update.

```
module FirstLastAge
    def first
        [array with 2000 names...to big to paste here].sample
    end
    def last
        [array with 1000 names...to big to paste here].sample
    end
    def rand_age
        rand(1..111)
    end
end
```

I also put module_function :first, :last, :rand_age now. so I can call them as FirstLastAge.rand_name.

Comment: You model obviously adds instance methods to your classes and you want to add class methods. Please share your `FirstLastAge` module.

Comment: I have updated my post. But as I said in my first try, without AR, it's working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first result, the reason why you got 2 errors is:

1. You forgot to define `first` in your console, I guess that you was trying to call `a.first` instead
2. You tried to call `User.rand_age` but it's a instant method not a class method, so you can't call it by this way.

As for the second result, it has some slightly different with the first result. You used instant methods (`User.new.first` and `User.new.rand_age`) instead of using class method, so yeah, your code is working.